# Looking for a customizable "Did you know..." dialog application

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, search, zenity

I want to deploy a "Did you know..." or "Tip of the day" application at the office. It should:

- Show a dialog at login time with a random tip.
- Obviously, provide some way to store my own tips.
- Be easy to disable and reenable by the user itself.

I'm using puppet, so I'm covered with the deployment. The tips don't even need to be gathered from a server, since I can deploy the newest tips file/database with no costs.

Sure, I could hack a quick solution by using zenity and bash, but I'd like to know if there's any application out there specifically targeted at this.

I don't like the zenity approach very much because it's very limited on the contents that can be displayed. No text alongside screenshots, for example. Zenity is aimed towards displaying simple dialogs.

Comment: You could use [yelp](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/yelp/) to display your tips if you're willing to write them in xml or html.

Comment: I like this approach. I can write this script, but I how can I put my custom xml or html into yelp?

Comment: Check out [yad](http://code.google.com/p/yad/), a fork of Zenity with many improvements.

Comment: You can pass a file as an argument to `yelp`.

Comment: As for `yad`, thanks, it has more options than `zenity`, but it's still very limited on hwo to position the images, and only displays pango markup text. As for `yelp`, what kind of files does it take? I tried passing some HTML files, and it just open them on a Chromium browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hacking a quick solution with Python using Python-webkit. This solution displays HTML files

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk,webkit,os
from random import choice

win = gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())

scroller = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
win.add(scroller)

web = webkit.WebView()
scroller.add(web)

banners = ["banner1","banner2","banner3"]
banner = choice(banners)

web.load_uri("file:///usr/local/lib/tips/"+banner+".html")

win.resize(640,400)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Place the corresponding banners on `/usr/local/lib/tips/`, for example, the `banner1.html` is a simple image:

```
<html><head><style>*,html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}</style></head><body></body><img src='banner1.png' /></html>
```

If you reference resources (images, css, js...), place them also in `/usr/local/lib/tips/`.

Then, run this python script at session start, by creating a desktop file on `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a lot like a graphical interface to `fortune` with a custom fortunes database.

## Creating the Custom Fortunes Database

1. Create a text file containing all of the tips you want to display.  Each tip should be on its own line, and there should be line containing only the `%` character after every tip.
2. Run `strfile -c % tips tips.dat` to produce a file suitable for use with `fortune`

## Installing `fortune` and the Tips

1. Run `sudo apt-get install fortune-mod` to get the `fortune` program.
2. Now place `tips` and `tips.dat` in /usr/share/games/fortunes.  If there are other files already there, those fortunes will display intermixed with your tips; you may wish to remove them.

## Graphical Interface

There are unfortunately not many options for graphically displaying fortunes.  You can either install `xcowsay`, which is in the normal repositories, or install the Wanda the Fish indicator applet from its PPA: https://launchpad.net/~dylanmccall/+archive/indicator-fish.  Both of these can be configured to start when a user logs in.  I believe only `xcowsay` can display images, however.

Neither of these programs are particularly professional looking, as `xcowsay` has a talking cow and indicator-fish a cartoon fish accompanying each fortune.  If that is a concern for you, you'll likely be better off writing your own graphical wrapper for `fortune`.

Comment: Thanks, but the graphical interface part turns me down completely :(